# To check weekday of a month

Tags: c#, date, calendar

I have a date such as April,1,2009. I want to know what the weekday is, i.e. whether April 1 is a Monday, Tuesday etc. Likewise I want to check weekday of each day in the month of April.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property:

```
new DateTime(2009, 4, 1).DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer language of choice doesn't have a `DayOfWeek` function, you can use [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) which returns the day of the week using simple integer arithmetic.